# Show $A \times B$ has Lebesgue-measure zero, when $m_n (A) =0$ and $B$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A\subset \Bbb{R^p}$ has Lebesgue measure zero, and that $B\subset \Bbb{R^{n-p}}$ is bounded. Show that $m_n ( A \times B ) =0$.

$B$ is bounded, $\exists R>0$ such that $B\subset B(0,R)\subset\Bbb{R^{n-p}}$. Then $$A\times B \subset A \times B(0,R).$$

We need to show that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists compact intervals $I_k$, such that $$A\times B \subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$$

and $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(I_k)<\epsilon.$$

How can I find the appropriate intervals $I_k$?

Comment: Suppose you start with intervals in $\mathbb R^p$ that cover $A$.  Can you get corresponding intervals in $\mathbb R^p \times \mathbb R^{n-p}$ to cover $A \times B$?  Will it help to reduce to the case where $B$ is an interval?

Comment: If I treat $B$ as an interval, then we'd have that $B\subset I = [-R,R]$, which is compact. Then $A\times B$ is covered, but one would also need to show the sum of the measures of these intervals is less than $\epsilon >0$

Comment: If you know the $p$-dimensional measure of interval $I_k$, what is the $n$-dimensional measure of $I_k \times [-R,R]$?